# Deobfuscation for Cordova apps

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, proguard, google-play-console

Each time I'm uploading a `Cordova`-based app (game) I can see: `There is no deobfuscation file associated with this App Bundle. If you use obfuscated code (R8/proguard), uploading a deobfuscation file will make crashes and ANRs easier to analyse and debug. Using R8/proguard can help reduce app size`

Is it possible to remove this warning? I'm a bit surprised it's not automatically optimizes to not to display the warning as it looks like something common.

It's really hard to find any information regarding this topic, especially when coming from `Web` background. I could only see an opinion the process of modyfing `proguard` files might break a `Cordova` app: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56605765/11127383.